# Is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$? But why is the limit necssarily approaching $0^+$ but not $0$?

Comment: No, it is not true.

Comment: the first equality is true, but the second is not. and yes $x \sin(1/x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ (for $x$ real ! not anymore when $x$ is complex...), hence $x \to 0^+$ or $x \to 0^-$ gives the same result

Answer (score 1):

No this is not true. Note $|\sin x|\leq 1\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, so then for all positive $x$ $$-1/x\leq \frac{\sin x}{x}\leq 1/x$$
Taking the limit as $x$ tends to infinity of both sides and using the squeeze theorem leads to $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$$

Note that the first part of your equality is generally true, but your second isn't, because $$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$$ is only a valid limit if your entire $\theta$ term tends to $0$. In your case $1/x\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ so you cannot use the identity.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. As $x \to \infty$, $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 0$ since $\sin$ is bounded.

As $x \to 0^+$,  $x \sin \frac 1x \to 0$. The reason is because, generally, if

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(\frac 1x) = L$$ If you want to understand why, note that in any neighbourhood $(0, \delta)$, $\frac 1x$ takes on arbitrarily large positive values and is monotone. By assumption, when it is sufficiently large, $f$ is arbitrarily close to $L$. We can make $\frac 1x$ large enough (and positive) by making $x$ small enough and (positive).

For this particular example, we can have simply $0$ rather than $0^+$ since the left hand limit exists as well, which can be shown with similar reasoning. More simply, we can also use squeeze theorem.

Comment: How about $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$?

Comment: @CoolKid Yes, that's true.